# Why do these visit methods cause memory leaks?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, visitor-pattern

I am working on a medium sized C++ framework making use of the visitor pattern.

A valgrind test of a program implementing this framework reported a number of memory leaks that could be tracked down to one of the visitors, namely the `copyCreator`.

```
template<typename copyNodeType>
struct copyCreator {
    copyCreator {}
    copyCreator(node * firstVisit) {
        firstVisit->accept(*this);
    }

    ~copyCreator() {
        copy.reset();
        for(auto ptr : openList) {
            delete ptr;
        }
    }

    std::unique_ptr<copyNodeType> copy = 0;
    vector<nonterminalNode *> openList;

    // push to tree
    template<typename nodeType>
    void push(nodeType * ptr) {
        if (copy) {
            // if root is set, append to tree
            openList.back()->add_child(ptr);
        }
        else {
            auto temp = dynamic_cast<copyNodeType *>(ptr);
            if(temp) {
                copy = std::unique_ptr<copyNodeType>(temp);
            }
        }
    }

// ...

    void visit(struct someNonterminalNode & nod) {
    auto next = new someNonterminalNode(); //This is leaked
    push(next);
    openList.push_back(next);
    nod.child->accept(*this);
    openList.pop_back();
};
```

There are a two main reasons why I am confused about this:

- The two different constructors cause a different number of leaks
- The leaks are reported to occur during visits

The `accept` methods of all nodes simply triggers a standard double dispatch to the `visit` method of the correct visitor.

I am fairly new to C++ programming and might have overlooked some really fundamental issue.

Comment: I can see why `copyCreator<programNode> cpy2(&globalScope, a);` would leak. `copyCreator<T>` expects that the very first node it visits is of type `T`. It creates and immediately leaks all other node types, until it encounters its first `T`. But `a` is not a `programNode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copyCreator<nodeType>::push(ptr)` is supposed to take ownership of `ptr`. But it fails to do so if (a) `ptr` is not of type `nodeType*` (as determined by `dynamic_cast`), and (b) no node of type `nodeType` has been visited yet.

In other words, `copyCreator<nodeType>` creates, and promptly leaks, copies of all nodes until it encounters one of type `nodeType`.

This is precisely what happens in `copyCreator<programNode> cpy2(&globalScope, a);`, where `a` is `forallNode*`. `cpy2` expects to encounter `programNode` (which it never does), and meanwhile, it copies and leaks all other nodes.

Comment: Excellent answer, I completely overlooked that!
I added a else {delete ptr;} after the dynamic_cast check in the push method and all leaks are gone. :)
There is still something odd going on with an Invalid read afterwards but I suppose that's because the deleted pointer is still accessed incorrectly somewhere... I should be able to handle that.
Thanks a lot for your help, it's very much appreachiated!